# recursive entity w/out parent/child relationship

Tags: sql, recursion, recursive-query

I'm trying to represent the following recursive relationship in a RDBMS:

[image]

As a basic example, we have the following fields:

```
1 - computer science
2 - computer engineering
3 - electrical engineering
4 - mathematics
```

And I want to relate similar fields to each other.  I could use a second table to relate fields to each other.  Optimally, I could imagine it looking like this:

```
+----------+----------+
| field1   | field2   |
+----------+----------+
|    4     |    1     | (math -> comp sci)
|    4     |    2     | (math -> comp eng)
|    4     |    3     | (math -> elect eng)
|    2     |    1     | (comp eng -> comp sci)
|    2     |    3     | (comp eng -> elect eng)
+----------+----------+
```

However, if the key were (field1, field2), I can see two potential issues:

1. Tuples could be duplicated, albeit unordered
2. It may complicate the queries unnecessarily if there is no importance to which field is in which column (as **sgeddes** points out, querying both columns and filtering out duplicates)

For example:

```
+----------+----------+
| field1   | field2   |
+----------+----------+
|    1     |    4     | (comp sci -> math)
|    4     |    3     | (math -> elect eng)
|    4     |    2     | (math -> comp eng)
|    3     |    4     | (elect eng -> math)
|    2     |    1     | (comp eng -> comp sci)
|    3     |    2     | (elect eng -> comp eng)
|    1     |    2     | (comp sci -> comp eng)
+----------+----------+
```

**How should I approach a non-hierarchical recursive relationship?**

Should I go ahead and intentionally duplicate each tuple, like in the second table?  Or is there another method that I am over-looking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen that approach several times.  Never been a huge fan honestly as I've had to query both fields for the matches and filter out duplicated results.  And what about more than 2 fields that are similar?  Can get rather messy.

Using your example above, another approach would be to introduce a SimilarField table.  It would store SimilarId and FieldId (and some people would argue a third Identity field, SimilarFieldId).  So if English and Literature were similar fields, then you could have:

```
SimilarId   FieldId
1           1         (English)
1           2         (Literature)
```

This approach allows you to have a 1-n relationship between your fields and their similar fields.

**--EDIT--**

In response to your comment, not sure how your example doesn't work:

```
SimilarId   FieldId
1           1         (English)
1           2         (Literature)
1           3         (Reading)
2           2         (Literature)
2           4         (History)
3           4         (History)
3           5         (Art History)
```

You can have as many grouped similar fields as needed.

To get all the Fields associated with Literature for example, your query could look like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT F.FieldId, F.FieldName
FROM Field F JOIN 
      SimilarField S ON F.FieldId = S.FieldId
WHERE S.SimilarId IN (
      SELECT SimilarId 
      FROM SimilarField
      WHERE FieldId = 2 
   )
```

And here is a sample [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/dbc83/1).

Comment: I may be confused (still), but I think I need many-to-many, and your example would only allow Literature to have one similar field. *(I updated the example in my question)*

Comment: @DavidKaczynski -- I'm pretty sure using this approach you can an N-N relationship in that regard, but a 1-N relationship in similar groups.  See edits above.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  Please allow me to ask this then:  if I want to get all of the fields similar to reading, how would that query look?  for example, `select SimilarId, FieldId from SimilarField where SimilarId = 3 or FieldId = 3`...but then how do I turn the resulting `(SimilarId, FieldId)` tuples into a set of individual Ids to query the original Field table?

Comment: @DavidKaczynski -- np, I have edited and included a sample fiddle.  Mind you, this is just one approach :)

Answer (score 1):

One common approach to the duplication problem is to make sure `field1` always contains the lowest id in the tuple, combined with an `UNIQUE` key on both columns. Then your condition for `SELECT` can just be `WHERE field1 = @id OR field2 = @id`.